# npm install invalid protocol error

Tags: node.js, proxy

I am new to nodejs.

As I am trying to install `ejs` via `npm` on my local windows system. But it gives me error invalid protocol: `192.168.1.201`. I have attached the screen shot.

Earlier I was using the same PC on a corporate proxy. But recently we have removed all proxies from the system. After removing all proxy settings everything is working fine. But still on few places I am getting this error message.

I have tried almost all possible commands to remove proxy from everywhere. But still I am not able to install `ejs`. I am also facing the same problem while installing `express framework` in `nodejs`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now the issue has been resolved. It was related to proxy settings. Earlier I tried to remove all the proxy from system but wasn't getting any success.

After removing proxy from the windows registry it started working properly.